# "search" field to filter content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple "search field", what it does is it searches if typed in text is equal to any data-attr of the boxes in the content and if so, hide everything but what found, something similar (this ain't working):

css:

```
.filter-div {
    display: none;
}
```

html:

```
    <label for="search">Search Input:</label>
    <input type="search" name="filter" id="search" value="" />
    <div class="filter-div" data-filter="one">one</div>
    <div class="filter-div" data-filter="two">two</div>
    <div class="filter-div" data-filter="three">three</div>
    <div class="filter-div" data-filter="four">four</div>
    <div class="filter-div" data-filter="five">five</div>
```

jquery:

```
    // save the default value on page load
    var filter = $('.input').val();

    // on submit, compare
    if ( $('.input').val() = $("data-filter") {
         $(this).show();
    } ​
```

I am also not sure if the content should be filtered with a button click or found content should pop up as click-able text in the search, or should all happen auto? Finally probably I will have to check it against more than one data-attr.

Anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#search').on('keyup', function() {
    var val = $.trim(this.value);
    if (val) {
        $('div[data-filter=' + val + ']').show();
    } else $('div[data-filter]').hide();
});
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/fKFJ5/6/)**

### According to demo fiddle example in comment

```
var divs = $('div[data-filter]');
$('#search').on('keyup', function() {
    var val = $.trim(this.value);
    divs.hide();
    divs.filter(function() {
        return $(this).data('filter').search(val) >= 0
    }).show();
});

divs.on('click', function() {
    divs.not(this).hide();
    var text = $.trim($(this).text());
    $('#search').val(text);
});
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/fKFJ5/11/)**

Comment: @rob.m check my answer and comment if you want something more or different

Comment: am i correct by saying this will check against ANY data-attr in the html? If so perfect, so i won't have to use different ones for different data-attr i may have

Comment: @rob.m it will check for all `div`s with `data-filter` attribute

Comment: I DVed for a sec because I thought the OP wanted a the filter value to be a part of not equal to the search string. Check it, it's back now.

Comment: @rob.m You don't need to use a class at all you can just attach to `[data-filter]` for both css and jQuery selection. And if you want it to show items if it matches the filter result partially my answer covers that.

Comment: @iambriansreed I think OP used class for `CSS` purpose, to hide them initially

Comment: @iambriansreed I also know. It's OP's choice, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @thecodeparadox I know he can use `[data-filter] { display: none; }`. See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/xMwS5 Documentation: http://w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Comment: ye don't worry, the class and css part wasn't the most important anyway. Is it possible to display a list of all the results when start typing? But not hide them until we either click on a pop up text result or hit the submit?

Comment: @rob.m what do you mean by all results? all one, two, three..? and which popup or submit button? please include it in my fiddle and share link

Comment: sorry, something similar to google search, the idea is to "search" probably some 100s boxes and user may not know the exact name, so a pop up result list bases on typed letter would be ideal

Comment: found an example of auto complete, be good to do something similar but based on data-filter attribute matches (apologies kinda evolving my question): http://jsfiddle.net/zkVrs/

Comment: ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302534/sorting-autocomplete-ui-results-based-on-match-location

Comment: lets nail it down if we can, basically this would be some ideal solution and real situation: http://jsfiddle.net/zkVrs/48/ - when the pop up appears, and we "hit" correct searched result, we .hide() the rest but the one we searched (i know we're taking this somewhere else from the question)

Comment: @rob.m I think my code also works for http://jsfiddle.net/zkVrs/52/ and we should stop it here, mate. If you want more than through another question, please

Comment: yep, yours is just perfect for what i asked and I accept it. I basically didn't know about the autocomplete plugin and has evolved my question and thought on it, to conclude check this: http://jsfiddle.net/m5HKX/1/

Comment: @thecodeparadox yep, that's it, guess what? Not sure why all that code was needed, look at a slimmer one: http://jsfiddle.net/m5HKX/13/

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript:

```
var filter_div = $('[data-filter]');
$('#search').keyup(function(){
    var val = $.trim(this.value);
    filter_div.hide();
    if(val.length == 0) return;
    filter_div.filter(function(){            
        return $(this).data('filter').indexOf(val)>-1
    }).show();

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/xMwS5/

​