# jQuery-ui autocomplete multiple values sort results alphabetically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sorting, jquery-ui-autocomplete

With reference to this question [Sorting Autocomplete UI Results based on match location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302534/sorting-autocomplete-ui-results-based-on-match-location), there is a solution that provides for single value jQuery autocomplete but is it possible to get a similar solution for multiple values jQuery autocomplete (http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference here is that you need to make sure and call `extractLast` like the demo you linked to is doing. Here's the complete code that should work with multiple values (pay particular attention to the `source` option):

```
$("#tags")
    .on("keydown", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    })
    .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function (request, response) {
            var term = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(extractLast(request.term))
                // Create two regular expressions, one to find suggestions starting with the user's input:
                , startsWithMatcher = new RegExp("^" + term, "i")
                , startsWith = $.grep(source, function(value) {
                    return startsWithMatcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
                })
                // ... And another to find suggestions that just contain the user's input:
                , containsMatcher = new RegExp(term, "i")
                , contains = $.grep(source, function (value) {
                    return $.inArray(value, startsWith) < 0 &&
                        containsMatcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
                });            

            // Supply the widget with an array containing the suggestions that start with the user's input,
            // followed by those that just contain the user's input.
            response(startsWith.concat(contains));
        },
        focus: function () {
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var terms = split(this.value);
            terms.pop();
            terms.push(ui.item.value);
            terms.push("");
            this.value = terms.join(", ");
            return false;
        }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Aa5nK/1/

Comment: Thank you! Finally found what I was exactly looking for.. Neat solution

Answer (score 0):

In the response, you should return a list of result that match what you want in your query:

e.g.

```
list_of_terms = {"term0","term1","term2",...};

$("#inputsearch").autocomplete({
    var term = request.term
    var list = new Array();
    source: function( request, response ) {
        var cnt = 0;
        $.each(list_of_terms, function(i) {
            var rSearchTerm = new RegExp('^' + RegExp.quote(term),'i');
            if (list_of_terms[i].match(rSearchTerm)) {                 
                list[cnt] = list_of_terms[i];
                cnt++;
            }
       });
     response(list);
    }
});



RegExp.quote = function(str) {
    return (str+'').replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");
};
```

provided i didn't miss a parenthesis, this should give you multiple values in your dropdown if the term entered equals the start of a term in your list_of_terms array

Comment: Where does this go? looks like this is out the code box - RegExp.quote = function(str) { return (str+'').replace(/([.?*+^$[]\(){}|-])/g, "\$1"); };

Comment: this is javascript.  it goes in script tags for javascript.  you link it to your input box by the input boxed id

Comment: Where does this code - `RegExp.quote = function(str) { return (str+'').replace(/([.?*+^$[]\(){}|-])/g, "\$1"); };` go? Because it is outside the grey box in the answer.

Comment: That too goes into the javascript. It should be in the gray.  I'll fix that